# How to show/hide windows by their wm name (_NET_WM_NAME) using libxdo or other x library?

Tags: c, window, x11, xlib, xdotool

With the [xdo](https://github.com/baskerville/xdo) command-line tool, you can target a window by its wm name using the `-a` switch. For example:

```
xdo hide -a Foo
```

Whereas in the xdo library for C, libxdo, you can only target windows by their window ID. How do you get the window ID with knowledge of only the wm name (`_NET_WM_NAME`)?

Something like

```
Window my_window = xdo_get_window_by_wm_name(xdo, "Foo")
```

is what I'm looking for, is there anything that does this?

Ultimately I'm trying to show/hide windows by their `_NET_WM_NAME`, is there an alternative or better way of doing this in C (with libxdo or otherwise)?

Comment: I have no idea how that `libxdo` library works, but with the standard `libX11` library, you can recursively enumerate all the windows from the root with `XQueryTree` and get any of their properties with `XGetWindowProperty`. Similar functions exist in libxcb (which is a newer alternative to libX11, but sum total just as bad as the old libX11).

Comment: and looking at the `xdo` source code, that's exactly what it does, using `libxcb`, with the important distinction that `-a` will __not__ match on `_NET_WM_NAME`, but on the old non-utf8 icccm `WM_NAME` property.